# Gaining weight despite diet

Tags: weight-loss, calories

I have been logging my food for past month and have constantly ate 750 cal. less than my resting energy. Despite all of this I am gaining weight! Can anyone decode what could be wrong?
I have eaten carbs like 30-40% of time, but the average input calories are always less than my resting energy by ~750 calories.

**Profile:**

- 40 years old Male
- 5'10
- 220 pounds
- Light active(3 miles walk/day, 15 min run every other night)
- Input calories/day ~1700 calories
- Required Energy ~2400 Calories (based on https://www.actx.edu/respiratory/files/filecabinet/folder14/2305_MetaSCal.pdf)
- Added 3 pounds(fluctuating)

Comment: Could you tell us how much weight do/did you gain?

Comment: Also, how did you determine your resting energy expenditure?

Comment: please see updated question. I used the online calculators to determine expenditure which gives minimum of 2400 calories.

Comment: Owing to water 3 pounds can be gained pretty fast. So if you just gained 3 pounds and they are even fluctuating you shouldn't worry at all. But I guess the reason you do not loose weight could be the slow metabolism which probably comes from the lack of activity in your case. 1700 kcal could actually be too much. But before concluding this: do you feel hungry or full during the day and/or at night?

Comment: @stew.nesc I understand but I expected to lose at least some weight. The math doesn't just add up.I feel so so during the day and hungry at night.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are gaining weight because you are not eating 750 cal/day less than your Resting Energy Expenditure.

1) The formulas provided in your linked document are estimates, not measurements.  While version 1 estimates your REE at 2420, version 2 estimates it at 2060.  The size of this discrepancy might be due to these estimators being derived from a sample of "healthy people" and if you are trying to lose weight because your 220 pounds @ 5'10" is from being obese, you might be outside of the population they were studying when constructing these estimators.

2) You may be eating more than the 1700 cal you believe, but that isn't important just now.

To get a reliable REE you probably need to have it measured, but in order to lose weight, you simply need to curtail your caloric intake some more.  Cut back a bit more on your food and keep monitoring the results.

Comment: Agreed. Generally, portion sizes are grossly underestimated - especially in the US, making it easy to think you’re taking in, say, 500 calories only to be really taking in 1000 calories. This has to do with serving sizes being disproportionate to what comes in the package.

Answer (score 1):

Gwaigh is right. If you weight is too elevate, you have probably disturb your body. You can not compare you to others people at this point. 
The fatter you have been, the less you have to eat after that. And if you eat too much (and badly), you will gain fat more easily than "normal" persons (you can't kill fat cells, so they will fill this directly). It's sad but true.

The easiest way to mesure to loose weight is to cut calories each week / 2 weeks. When you don't loose weight for 2 weeks, note how many calories you eat by day. It's you're maintenance, and you can start calc with this number.